# Capture SeekBar values

Tags: android, seekbar

In my android application I have a `TextView` and a `SeekBar`. Both the values are used for calculating result on a button click.

The problem is how to capture the `SeekBar` value and convert it into String for the calculation.

The code is below:

```
class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String a,b;
        Integer vis;
        a = txtbox3.getText().toString();
        b = slider1.getContext().toString();
        vis = (Integer.parseInt(a)*Integer.parseInt(b))/100;
        tv.setText(vis.toString());
    }
}
```

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25):

You are looking for the method [getProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getProgress()) of the `ProgressBar` class as `SeekBar` is a subclass of `ProgressBar`.

So basically it would be something like that.

```
int value = seekBar.getProgress();
```

Also I don't really understand why you want to convert an int to a String just so you can convert that String to an Integer later. It does not make any sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can store the progress value into a global integer variable. 
Then you can use it easily where ever you want. 
Try this Code. 
It will help you...

```
int p=0;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

final TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    final SeekBar seek=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
final Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        p=progress;
    }
});


 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String a = textView.getText().toString();
        vis = (Integer.parseInt(a)*p)/100;
            text.setText(vis.toString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// variable in top 
String infos;
//-----`enter code here`

// defaultSeekBar (assign by your id)
defaultSeekBar.setOnProgressChangedListener(new ProgressListener(){
            @Override
            public void invoke(int i) {
                Log.d("VALUE",""+ i);
                infos = String.valueOf(defaultSeekBar.getProgress());
                textViewDefaultSeek.setText(infos);
            }

            });
```

Comment: Could you please add a bit of text to accompany this code and share how it responds to the question?